# what should be the right query to get below result from the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write a query to solve the below problem :

I have a table called kids with 2 columns :

```
kids_name varchar2(20) ,
flag_color varchar2(20)
```

Entries in the above table are like below :

```
A     red
B     red
C     blue
D     red
A     blue
B     blue
F     red
G    yellow
A    yellow
B    Green
```

I want to write a query to display the name of those kids who has both red and blue flags.

So, with the above table the query should return :

```
A
B
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to use `HAVING` and `DISTINCT`

```
select kids_name
from your_table
where flag_color in ('red', 'blue')
group by kids_name
having count(distinct flag_color) = 2
```

Comment: This solution fulfils my expectations. Thanks alot Mr. Radim Baca.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Exists`

```
select * from tablename a 
where exists (select 1 from tablename b 
     where a.kids_name=b.kids_name and flag_color in ('red', 'blue') having count(*)>1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select kids_name
from your_table
where flag_color in ('red', 'blue')
group by kids_name
having count(*) > 1   // you can have count(*) > 1  if you want students with total count as 2 only.
```

As per the data set, there is no repetition in the rows otherwise you will have to create distinct rows first and then you will have to run this query on that result set.

`having count(distinct flag_color) = 2`as mentioned by `Radim Bača` is good.